# C# assignment thread safe

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

Is the following assignment code thread safe?

```
public Stream Stream
{
    get
    {
        return stream ?? (stream = new NetworkStream(Socket));
    }
    set
    {
        stream = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Thread safe" is a bit vague term. Could you describe precisely the requirements that this code should satisfy, in order to be considered thread safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It it entirely possible that set setter is called, after stream is evaluated (being null), but before the new NetworkStream is assigned. This would mean that the newly set stream (via the setter) is overwritten with the new NetworkStream.